# How to perform a DELETE request using the Django REST Framework?

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have gone through the Django REST Framework tutorials completely and cannot find a way to delete the test JSON that I created using POST. I don't have a strong understanding of how Django chooses the methods to get called, but here is what I have so far:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def snippet_detail(request, pk, format=None):
   """
   Retrieve, update, or delete a snippet instance.
   """
    try: 
        snippet = Snippet.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Snippet.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method == 'DELETE':
        snippet.delete()
        return HttpResponse(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Comment: Just to make sure, what seems to be the problem? What happens when you make a DELETE request?

Comment: @GregSadetsky Well that's the thing, there is no interface to make the DELETE request and I am not sure how to make it from the tutorial.

Comment: Django (and Django REST Framework) only provide the server side which replies to HTTP queries; to make requests, you can see the [REST Framework tutorial](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/#testing-our-first-attempt-at-a-web-api) where [httpie](https://github.com/jkbrzt/httpie) is used to make requests. Another option is to use a product such as [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/). You can see more recommendations [here as well](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4486658/426790).

Answer (score 0):

```
@api_view(['DELETE'])
def delete (request,id):
    category = Categories.objects.get(pk = id)
    category.delete()
    result = {
                'status' : 'Done'
            }
    return Response(result, status = status.HTTP_200_OK)
```